# Suppose $f$ is a twice-differentiable function with $f(0) = 0$, $f\left(\frac12\right) = \frac12$ and $f'(0) = 0$...

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $f$ is a twice-differentiable function with $f(0) = 0$, $f\left(\frac12\right) = \frac12$ and $f'(0) = 0$. Prove that $|f''(x)| \ge 4$ for some $x \in \left[0,\frac12\right]$.

Could someone help me with this? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Go by contradiction.

Comment: It is easier to prove something slightly stronger: $f''(x) \geq 4$. Assume this inequality fails and then write $f(1/2)$ as a certain integral of $f''$.

Comment: From the mean value theorem, there exists a number $\xi\in(0,1/2)$ such that 

$$f(1/2)=f(0)+\frac12f'(0)=\frac{1}{8}f''(\xi)$$

Since $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, and $f(1/2)=1/2$, there exists a number $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that 

$$f''(\xi)=4$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-2x^2$. Then $g'(x)=f'(x)-4x$ and $g''(x)=f''(x) - 4$.

We have $g(0)=g(\frac 1 2)=0$, therefore there is $x_1 \in (0, \frac 1 2)$ such that $g'(x_1)=0$ (why?). Also $g'(0)=0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: $g'(0)$ is actually $-4$.

Comment: @Ian $g'(0)=f'(0)-4 \cdot 0 = 0$

Comment: *facepalm*, sorry, carry on.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt$ and $f'(x)=\int_0^x f''(t)\,dt$. If $f''(x)<4$ for all $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, what can you say about $f(\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: How do you know $f^{''}$ is Riemann integrable?